# AutoCompleteTextView OnItemClickListener null param (landscape mode on HTC Desire S)

Tags: landscape, autocompletetextview, onitemclicklistener, android

**My Problem :** I have an AutoCompleteTextView with an OnItemClickListener. This has been working fine for 18 months, but I have now noticed it throws a NullPointerException when I select an item in landscape mode on my HTC Desire S. (There is no error in portrait mode or on any other phone or emulator I've tested it on).

The `AdapterView<?> av` parameter is coming through as null. Why would this be, and how can I get around it?

**Code :**

```
myAutoCompleteTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.myAutoCompleteTextView);
myAutoCompleteTextView.setSingleLine();

myAutoCompleteTextView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int index, long arg) {
        String selectedItem = (String)av.getItemAtPosition(index);  
        //Do stuff with selected item ...
    }
}
```

**Error :**

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException
    at uk.co.myCompany.mobile.android.myCompanymobile.pages.groups.AbstractGroupSelectionPage$3.onItemClick(AbstractGroupSelectionPage.java:228)
    at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.onCommitCompletion(AutoCompleteTextView.java:993)
    at com.android.internal.widget.EditableInputConnection.commitCompletion(EditableInputConnection.java:76)
    at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.executeMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:368)
    at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper$MyHandler.handleMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:86)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4385)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Extra Code - my custom adapter inner class :**

```
/**
 * An inner class to simply make a custom adapter in which we can alter the on-screen look of selected groups.
 */
private class SelectedGroupAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Group> {
    private ArrayList<Group> items;
    private int layout;

    public SelectedGroupAdapter(Context context, int layout, ArrayList<Group> items) {
        super(context, layout, items);
        this.items = items;
        this.layout = layout;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(layout, null);
        }                           
        Group o = items.get(position);

        //Display the group name and number of contacts
        if (o != null) {
            TextView groupName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.groupName);
            TextView noOfContacts = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.noOfContacts);
            if (groupName != null) {
                groupName.setText(o.getGroupName());
            }
            if(noOfContacts != null) {
                if (o.isDynamic())
                    noOfContacts.setText(getString(R.string.dynamic));
                else {
                    int contactsCount = o.getGroupSize();
                    if(contactsCount == 1) noOfContacts.setText(contactsCount + " " + getString(R.string.contact));
                    else noOfContacts.setText(contactsCount + " " + getString(R.string.contacts));
                }
            }
        }
        return v;
    }              
}
```

Comment: In your manifest for this Activity, are you by chance using `android:configChanges="orientation"`?

Comment: Yes I am : android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"/>

Comment: Error in this line AbstractGroupSelectionPage.java:228 what is this ?

Comment: Jason : I'm rather rusty on my android skills lately, and I can't remember exactly what this means? Does it simply allow both orientations?

Comment: Venky : Line 228 is  String selectedItem = (String)av.getItemAtPosition(index);  av is coming in as null for some reason.

Comment: Are you sure av is coming null? What you are trying to do in this line String selectedItem = (String)av.getItemAtPosition(index); ?

Comment: Yes av is null (but only on the HTS Desire S phone, and only when in landscape mode. It's fine in portrait mode or on other phones). The line of code gets the object that has been selected, and casts it to a String.

Comment: How you are filtering value for AutoComplete Adapter using String[] or ArrayList?

Comment: I am using my own custom adapter. It has an arraylist of items (of object Group, which is my own class). I have added this code to my question above.

Answer (score 0):

My hunch is that since you are declaring `android:configChanges="orientation"` in your manifest, then when you rotate the old `OnItemClickListener` is still sticking around, and since you technically have a new layout, the `AdapterView` that was being used prior to orientation change doesn't exist anymore, thus is null when you click on an item.

There's 2 things I think that would solve this if this is the case:

1. Remove the `orientation` option in your manifest. Any events you place in `configChanges` tells Android "I'm taking care of this configuration change, so let me handle it" as opposed to letting Android handle it. The normal operation for Android in the event of an orientation change is to destroy and recreate your `Activity` (it will take care of repopulating some `View`s with data automatically).
2. If you decide you need to handle orientation changes, then override `onConfigurationChanged()` and set the `OnItemClickListener` to the new `AdapterView` object (`ListView`, `GridView`, whichever you are using) that should have been recreated in the `onCreate` method.

Comment: I just tried option 1 but the null pointer still happened. Mmm, do you think this implies that your hunch was unfortunately incorrect?